# How would I create a bootable ssd with Linux that can work on multiple machines

Tags: ssd, bootable-media

I bought a ssd recently and am trying to make it bootable for Linux, I have downloaded the Linux .ISO onto a USB and have then installed Linux onto the ssd and partioned it with a 8gb swap, 500mb efi and the rest as the main storage. It works in my ok which I setup Ubuntu on but it isn’t bootable on any other device I plug it into. Anyone know why this might be the case.

Comment: What are you trying to boot? The SSD or the thumb drive?

Comment: Please elaborate on _"it isn’t bootable"_. It starts booting, but stops with an error? Gets stuck at GRUB? Doesn't show in the EFI menu?

Comment: yeah sorry so when i turn on my pc i hit f12 to go into the boot options. on my pc it shows it there. i can click it and i go into the ubuntu system and all is well. on my other devices i dont get the option to click it. and im booting the ssd which i installed ubuntu on

Comment: before the install of ubuntu i could pick the ssd as the drive to boot on but after the install it stopped for all  the devices other than the pc i did the install on